# What is the "Microsoft Application Virtualization Virtual Process Launcher" under "Open With"

Tags: windows-7

I got a laptop (Windows 7, x64) from my new employer and noticed that, when right-clicking on a text file, I see this option I have not seen on other computers I use:

[image]

I guess the appearance of the "Microsoft Application Virtualization Virtual Process Launcher" is not a bug because when I select it, it opens the text file in WordPad.

But what causes this option to be enabled? It is some service or setting?

Is selecting to open a text document in "Microsoft Application Virtualization Virtual Process Launcher" the same as opening it directly in WordPad, or does it provide some additional advantage?

Comment: [Getting Started with Microsoft Application Virtualization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2008.10.appv.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the MS App-V platform.

Here is an explanation from [shouldiblockit.com](http://shouldiblockit.com/appvlp.exe-9890.aspx):

> Microsoft Application Virtualization Virtual Process Launcher for Microsoft Application Virtualization (MS App-V) platform allows applications to be deployed in real-time to any client from a virtual application server. It removes the need for local installation of the applications. Instead, only the App-V client needs to be installed on the client machines. All application data is permanently stored on the virtual application server.